# Kubernetes's service still in pending status. How does it work and how to fix this issue?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, flannel

I have Kubernetes Cluster v1.10 over centos 7

when I deploy service type LoadBalancer it still in pending status

Do I need to know how LoadBalancer type work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you read the docs on the Kubernetes [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/) abstraction.

Depending on the Cloud or your infrastructure provider this could be several things

Generally, this means that the kube-controller manager can't create the load balancer in your cloud provider and the kubelet on your nodes can't add the routes to the service.

And, this could be because you don't have the right credentials, you don't have right cloud provider configured on Kubernetes, or you are running a completely bare-metal server, or you are running something like [minikube](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/minikube/), or simply you don't have connectivity to your cloud provider.

Comment: i am using a completely bare-metal server from OVH Provider

Comment: LoadBalancer will not work unless you are using something like OpenStack or integrating with hardware Load balancers like F5

Answer (score 1):

The way it works is that Kubernetes will need a load-balancer to configure ;-)
Since you don't have one, it cannot configure the load-balancer for you, and the status remains as pending.

Comment: it can handle by using ingress-controller OR assign public address for loadbalance how can i assign list of public IPs , i am using OVH cloud provider not google